# Javascript: Promise not working. .then executing before resolve completes

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, promise

First time working with promises.  I'm working with the google maps api to drop markers with setTimeout delays between markers and then clustering the markers. I have two promises. one to resolve the individual marker object from a location, and then another promise to return the array of marker objects for clustering purposes.  In the console i'm seeing the dump of `console.log('markers before clustering');` before i'm seeing `console.log('iteration: [' + timeout + '] value: [' + value +']');` which tells me `.then` is executing before `resolve` returns something.

In my code, `markers` is a blank variable and `locations` is a lat/lng object that is pre-defined.

Here is the console output:
markers before clustering 
maps.js:52 [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined] 
maps.js:77 markers after callback
maps.js:78 [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
maps.js:69 iteration: [0] value: [[object Object]]
maps.js:69 iteration: [1] value: [[object Object]]
maps.js:69 iteration: [2] value: [[object Object]]
maps.js:69 iteration: [3] value: [[object Object]]

CODE:

```
    function dropMarkers(markers) {
        //locations are passed in from php json.  variable is defined/populated prior to this .js file.
        let test = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        markers = locations.map(addMarkerWithTimeout);

        resolve(markers);
      });

      test.then(function(value){
        console.log('markers before clustering');

        //console dump is showing that markers are being populated correctly.  I believe the problem is with the .push method above
        console.log(value);
        clustering(value);
      });
    }


    function addMarkerWithTimeout(position, timeout) {
      let prom = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        window.setTimeout(function(){
          resolve(new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: position,
                  map: map,
                  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP}));
        }, timeout*300);
      });

      prom.then(function(value) {
        console.log('iteration: [' + timeout + '] value: [' + value +']');
        return value;
      });
    }


    //add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
    function clustering(markers) {
        console.log('markers after callback');
        console.log(markers);

        markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
        imagePath: 'images/m'});
    }
```

Comment: `addMarkerWithTimeout` doesn't return anything

Comment: If `locations` is a lat/lng object, what does `locations.map()` do? Did you mean that it's an array of lat/lng objects?

Comment: and when you fix `addMarkerWithTimeout` not returning anything, your `test` promise wont wait for all the markers to be resolved before the `test.then` callback is called

Comment: addMarkerWithTimeout is returning "value" in the prom.then section of code.

Comment: .map is a javscript function.  locations.map is an alternative way to iterate through an array compared to using a for loop.

Comment: @GriffinBurns `addMarkerWithTimeout is returning "value"` - returning a value inside a function that is inside a function does not mean the outer function is returning a value - programming 101

Comment: The callback to `prom.then()` returns a value (so the promise returned by `prom.then()` (yes, `.then()` returns a promise) will pass that value to it's then callback) but `addMarkerWithTimeout` does not return anything

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @geocodezip - there is code in the question that demonstrates the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In dropMarkers, you want to wait for all the markers to resolve - for this, `Promise.all` is the weapon of choice:

```
function dropMarkers(markers) {
    //locations are passed in from php json.  variable is defined/populated prior to this .js file.
    Promise.all(locations.map(addMarkerWithTimeout))
    .then(function(value){
        console.log('markers before clustering');

        //console dump is showing that markers are being populated correctly.  I believe the problem is with the .push method above
        console.log(value);
        clustering(value);
    });
}
```

If you are calling dropMarkers, and want to "wait" on the completion, simply `return Promise.all ...` and use

```
dropMarkers([]).then( ...
```

In `addMarkerWithTimeout` - you want to return a Promise

```
function addMarkerWithTimeout(position, timeout) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            resolve(new google.maps.Marker({
                position: position,
                map: map,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
            }));
        }, timeout*300);
    })
    .then(function(value) {
        console.log('iteration: [' + timeout + '] value: [' + value +']');
        return value;
    });
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: is there any other way other than using set time out? I mean the code should execute only when the promise above it with another nested promise inside above promise is resolved.